# Graphic debugger that can connect to gdbserver

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'm looking for a graphic debugger that can connect to a running gdbserver (TCP) and does provide a usable interface.

I need to watch multiple complex data structures while stepping through the program.

I tried DDD, but the look and handling was just to weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome comes with nemiver (but I haven't used it remotely to date)

I find I drop to gdb because I like to have lowlevel access. DDD has very nice examination features, don't underestimate the power of DDD

[OT: remember the days when GIMP was blindsided because the interface was... nonstandard?]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Eclipse with CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Comment: Do you know about a tutorial that describes how CDT can be configured to use a remote gdbserver?